# string conversion with exponential notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, scientific-notation

I have a value that has exponential notation in it which I wanted to covert to string in python, tried the below ways, but it gets converted e+100,

```
value=5066e97
str(value) results in '5.066e+100'
f'{value}' results in '5.066e+100'
value.__str__() results in '5.066e+100'
'{}'.format(tag) results in '5.066e+100'
```

But I want the result to be '5066e97' i.e., any value that has the exponential notation must be converted to string with quotes around it, what is the pythonic way to achieve it?

Comment: There is no such way. Regardless of what you have in your source code, `value` will always be stored as a floating point number and you will lose formatting. `5066e97`, `5.066e100`, `50.66e99` etc are all different represenations of the same number. You may consider making it a string (e.g. `value = "5066e97"`) and convert it to a float (`float(value)`) only when doing arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create your own formatting code to express the number as a multiple of `10**97`.

Seeing as `5066e97` is the same number as `5.066e100`, it's not worth it IMO, but here is one way:

```
def fmt_exponent(num, exponent, mantissa_precision=3):
    mantissa = num / 10**exponent
    return f"{mantissa:.{decimal_places}f}e{exponent:d}"

print(fmt_exponent(5066e97, 97, 0))  # 5066e97
print(fmt_exponent(5066e97, 100, 1)) # 5.1e100
```